# R speeding up calculation process on 2.5million obs

Tags: r, data.table, performance

I have a huge data.frame (2 million obs.) where I calculate the sum of multiple column values based on one identical column value, like this (convert to data.table first):

```
check <- dt[,sumOB := (sum(as.numeric(as.character(OB))), by = "BIK"]
```

This gives me a new column with the sum values of, where applicable multiple values with the same BIK. After I add the following calculation.

```
calc <- check[,NewVA := (((as.numeric(as.character(VA)))
/ sumOB) * (as.numeric(as.character(OB)))), by = ""]
```

This works perfectly fine, giving me a new column with the desired values. My dataframe contains of as said 2 million observations and this process is extremely slow and memory intensive (I have 8GB of ram and I use all of it).

I would like to speed up this process, is there a more efficient way to reach the same results?

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: How about giving a reproducible example and a test against which people can throw their code at?

Comment: I suggest to make profiling your code with a sample data (about 10k objects). I think a type convertions is bottleneck.

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov No, copying a huge data structure in memory is the bottleneck.

Comment: To make a reproducible example a simple matrix with 3 columns and 2.5 million rows with random values (ranging 150000 : 850000) would suffice. Tomorrow I will try the FREAD  to get rid of the as.XXX's

Answer (score 8):

I don't understand why you wrap everything in `as.numeric(as.character(...))`. That's a performance cost you shouldn't need.

Also why do you copy your data.table? That's your biggest mistake. Look at

```
dt[,sumOB := (sum(as.numeric(as.character(OB))), by = "BIK"] 
dt[,NewVA := 
  (((as.numeric(as.character(VA))) / sumOB) * (as.numeric(as.character(OB))))]      
print(dt)
```

(possibly without all that type conversions).

Comment: If I had to guess, the type conversions come from things being factors that shouldn't be factors, which of course they'd need to fix at the point of data import.

Comment: @joran That's my guess too. But if he used `fread` for data import (as he should) this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: wow... `fread` (from the `data.table` package) is magic. I am getting a hugely noticeable boost in IO performance over `read.table` for a large csv file. Thanks @Roland!!!

Comment: It is exactly because they are imported as factors (and yes, they should not be). I'm not the one who imports the data, I receive the .Rdata, will contact him and get back to this tomorrow. I copied the data.tables because I needed to check every step. I could remove the creation of extra data.tables but I can't see how this would speed up the process.

Comment: @Joran, sorry if I'm missing something here but I thought only strings will be loaded as factors (by default) in `read.table`. But it seems to be able to convert to `numeric` here.. So how did it get converted to `factor` while importing, in the first place?

Comment: @Arun Well, we don't know for sure what exactly was in the original file being read. Typically, people will accidentally read in a column that they "think" is numeric, but actually contains some stray character in a single value that messes everything up, or something.

Comment: @RobertLuyt If your slowdown is due to memory, then making copies of your data table is a contributing factor.

Comment: @joran It is weird, since the columns which I have to address with as.numeric(as.character) are in the complete database only numeric (or so it seems) but whenever I try to process them without the as.numeric(as.character) it doesn't work.

Comment: @RobertLuyt Well, I am _very_ certain that if your data really were purely numeric, it would be read as such. You'll need to examine the raw data very carefully.